# Why is the ring of Eisenstein integers interesting

Tags: eisenstein-integers

Also there's quite little information on its history. Can anyone please enlighten me in this ring. Particularly i had been researching about it but I feel its not quite enough to be a motivation to be researched upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the only (integer ring of a) quadratic extension with $6$ roots of unity.  And that's the most you can have.  The Gaussian integers have $4$.  Everyone else has $2$.  Isn't it amazing that 6th roots were packed into a mere quadratic extension?  The norm just squeezes in to that little gap that makes it possible.

Comment: The total awe and wonder of mathematical details packed into this answer is just wonderful.